# Is a mean of 12 unusual for a sample of size 30 from Exp(1/10)?

Tags: statistics

I am doing an assignment in my statistics course and have trouble with the following:

Maria claims that she has drawn a random sample of size 30 from the exponential distribution with $\lambda = 1/10$. The mean of her sample is $12$.

c) Is a mean of $12$ unusual for a sample of size $30$ from $Exp(1/10)$?

Is there any formal way to check this? I can't find any formal definition of "unusual" in my book. I am reading "Mathematical Statistics with Resampling and R" Laura Chichara.

TIA for any help.

Comment: Hint: find the distribution of the sample mean, and find the probability of getting a mean greater than or equal to 12 for a sample size of 30

Comment: I was asked in the problem before to do a simulation in R in regards to what you just said and found that $P(\bar{X} \geq 12) \approx 0.15$ (it of course changes for every simulation I do). But how I do then conclude if it is unusual? Of course if it only occurs approximately in $15/100$ times it is not usual but would it be considered unusual?

Comment: i believe there's no rigorous definition of the word "unusual", you can probably explain verbally whether a probability of 0.15 is considered "usual" in common sense terms

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not unusual.

"Usually" do define an "unusual" value one refers to the fact that this events happens in less than $5\%$ of the times.

In your exercise, before getting the distribution of the sample mean, first observe that

$$E(\overline{X}_{30})=10$$

$$V(\overline{X}_{30})=\frac{10}{3}$$

thus we have a sigma of $\sigma=\sqrt{3.33}\approx 1.83$

in a Gaussian approx, unusual values are over $2\sigma$, that is in your 30 size sample to have a value greater than $10+1.83\times2=13.66$

Additionally, your size 30 sample from an exponential is good to be approximated with a gaussian.

---

Of course, if you want to have a more precise result, you can derive the distribution of your sample mean, that is

$$\overline{X}_{30}\sim \text{Gamma}(30;3)$$

and thus

$$6\cdot\overline{X}_{30}\sim \chi_{(60)}^2$$

Using the tables, you get that the 95% quantile is 13.18 thus 12 is perfectly in the expected range; In fact, your 12 is included in the 86.21% quantile